# custom controls and query string(asp.net)

Tags: asp.net

How to call a custom control when   query string is changed?

My example not work?Why?

```
  <% if(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"])==6){  %>


 <answer:answer_n id="give_me_top_five_news" runat="server" />
     <%} %>


<% if(Request.QueryString["do"]=="registracija"){
       Page.Header.Title = "HHHHH";

        %>
   <reg:f_reg id="custom_controls_for_registration" runat="server" />

    <%} %>
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more details?

Answer (score 0):

Changed in what fashion?  Anytime you load the page with a new URL and query string, the page will be loaded for the first time.  You would have to save the info you wanted to store in the Session (for example) and then in the Page_Load event check the query string vs the Session variable to see if they are the same or different.

There may be different ways to do it, but that's what comes to mind off the cuff.